# Is Wolfenstein (2009) a sequel or a reboot?

Tags: wolfenstein-2009

Is the Wolfenstein game released in 2009 a sequel to the 2004 Return to Castle Wolfenstein, or a reboot?

I cannot recall any references to the previous game in the 2009 game, although it does seem to be an entirely different adventure story-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is a sequel.

source: https://www.gamespot.com/reviews/wolfenstein-review/1900-6215937/

Comment: That review calls it a sequel, but is there any word from the developers on what they meant it to be?

Comment: No idea.. I've never played the game. Although, reviewers usually state whether a new game in a franchise is a reboot or a sequel.

Comment: Wikipedia also says it's a sequel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein

Comment: Is the 2004 RoCW a sequel or a reboot to the original 1992 Wolfenstein 3D? ;)

Comment: I'd say the RoCW is more a reboot.